# Is read() necessary before write() with SSH via PHPSecLib?

Tags: php, linux, ssh, phpseclib, libssh2

I have written a small script that issues a series of commands via `write()` to a linux machine, with a 5 second `sleep()` between each one. The exact same commands work when entered manually but despite being connected successfully, do not seem to work when used from a PHP script.

As this is the case, I am curious if using `read()` is absolutely necessary prior to issuing a `write()` command?

```
<?php

include('Net/SSH2.php');

    $serverhostname = "IP_HERE";
    $ssh_username = "root";
    $ssh_password = "PASS_HERE";

    // Establish new SSH2 Connection
    $connection = new Net_SSH2($serverhostname, 22);

    if($connection->login($ssh_username, $ssh_password))
    {
        echo "LOGGED IN! </br>";

        sleep(5);

        $result = $connection->write('en PASS_HERE\r\n');
        echo "RESULT: " . $result . " </br>";

        sleep(5);

        $result = $connection->write('configure terminal\r\n');
        echo "RESULT: " . $result . " </br>";

        sleep(5);

        $result = $connection->write('interface ve 110\r\n');
        echo "RESULT: " . $result . " </br>";

        sleep(5);

        $result = $connection->write('port-name Test_Brett\r\n');
        echo "RESULT: " . $result . " </br>";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "SSH Connection Failed. Check that the remote host is online and accepting connections!";
    }

?>
```

*UPDATE*

```
$result = $connection->write('en PASS_HERE\n');
$result = $connection->write('configure terminal\n');
$result = $connection->write('interface ve 110\n');
$result = $connection->write('port-name Test_Brett\n');
$connection->setTimeout(5);
echo $connection->read();
```

Comment: Is it correct to send \r\n here? When you do this interactively, you're probably hitting the enter key which I'd expect to only send \r.

Comment: In my experience it's \n that you need to send - not \r.

Comment: I was trying it with "\n", "\r", and "\r\n". The documentation said it would be one of the 3 depending on the OS, but I just happened to have "\r\n" set here. In most cases I have been using just "\n" for testing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just did this:

```
$connection->write("ls -la\n");
$connection->write("pwd\n");
$connection->setTimeout(5);
echo $connection->read();
```

And it seemed to perform the commands just fine without a `read()` between the two `write()`'s. But it could be that a `read()` has to be done, even if just once, at the end.

What I'd do if I were you is, instead of doing `sleep(5)` do `$connection->setTimeout(5); $connection->read();`. You can throw away the return value of `read()`. If you knew what to expect back you could just do `$connection->read('pattern')`, which would be faster, but if you don't, I'd do the `$connection->setTimeout(5);` route just to be on the safe side.

Comment: I tried that out (added the code I used to the original post as well) doing all the writes, then set timeout and read. I also tried just using echo $connection->read(); before each write as well. Both ways result in "Notice: Connection closed prematurely in /public_html/brocade/Net/SSH2.php on line 2303" after the first write() line, so I am very confused.

Comment: I guess seeing the logs of your successful connections and your failed ones would be helpful. You can get logs by doing `define('NET_SSH2_LOGGING', 3);` at the top of your file.